# Mysql :Query set is not working in python 

Tags: python, mysql

I am working with python mysql now

I am having a problem Here is mysql query

```
query = 'SELECT * FROM callerdetail WHERE screenname="1" AND status="0"AND agent ='idd'
```

WHERE i am getting idd from external source but whenever i am trying to execute this query

i am getting error

```
  File "server.py", line 28
    query = 'SELECT * FROM callerdetail WHERE screenname="1" AND status="0"AND agent ='idd'
                                                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Please help me out what i might doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use a query parameter:

```
query = 'SELECT * FROM callerdetail WHERE screenname="1" AND status="0"AND agent =?'
```

then pass in the value for `idd` when executing the query:

```
cursor.execute(query, (idd,))
```

In python, you cannot simply just put a variable in between various strings and hope it interpolates.

To do regular string interpolation, use the [`.format()` method](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings):

```
query = 'SELECT * FROM callerdetail WHERE screenname="1" AND status="0"AND agent = "{0}"'.format(idd)
```

but then you'll miss out on the database query optimizer preparing your statement. Prepared statements are faster to execute if used repeatedly.

Comment: So for more complicated queries where you have multiple variables you would simply add the variables to the tuple?

Comment: @raido: I'd still use multiple `?` query parameters, and use those values in the `.execute(query, tuple_of_parameters)` call.

Comment: Ah I see, so it takes from the tuple in order?  So the first ? would take tuple[0] and the second ? would take tuple[1]?

Comment: See [How to use variables in SQL statement in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/902408) Note that different database adapters use different parameter styles, see http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/

Comment: And I linked to the documentation for the `.format()` function, yes, `{0}, {1}, {2}` would refer to positional arguments to the `.format()` function for interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing double and single quotes.

instead of...

```
query = 'SELECT * FROM callerdetail WHERE screenname="1" AND status="0"AND agent = 'idd'
```

use...

```
query = 'SELECT * FROM callerdetail WHERE screenname="1" AND status="0"AND agent = "idd"'
```

Also, is idd a variable?  If it is you need to do...

```
query = 'SELECT * FROM callerdetail WHERE screenname="1" AND status="0"AND agent = "'+str(idd)+'"'
```

Comment: my answer is actually two answers :D  I'm not sure if idd is a variable or the actual SQL values for agent so I proposed a second one the converts idd to a string for concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you forgot to concat the external variable in making of the query,

```
query = 'SELECT * FROM callerdetail WHERE screenname="1" AND status="0"AND agent = "'+idd+'"'
```